# jQuery and MooTools conflict with jQuery plugin

Tags: mootools, javascript, jquery

I have to use both MooTools and jQuery in a single page. I am using the featureCarousel jQuery slider plugin. There is a conflict between jQuery and MooTools. But the animation is not working perfectly even with `jQuery.noConflict()` function.

You can see the live demo of the issue [here](http://mejoyal.com/help/).

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

Comment: there never really is a need to mix libraries... IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading JQuery and call noConflict() before loading the MooTools. Otherwise MooTools will use the $ namespace before you can call noConflict().

It doesn't look like you're using MooTools at all in the example. Also the animation seems to be working fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Mootools added at the 8th line. sometimes it works but if you reload it again, it doesn't work